# Chrome extension cross-domain AJAX gives NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I'm creating a Disqus notifier Chrome extension. This involves making an HTTP call to disqus.com, but I can't get the AJAX call through - Chrome gives me the famous `NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101` error.

I read somewhere (can't recall where) that Chrome will block cross-domain AJAX calls from unpacked extension, so I've also tried packing my extension - but same result. I also understand that I can't do cross-domain AJAX from anywhere but a background page.

*manifest.json:*

```
{
 "name": "Disqus notifier",
 "version": "1.0",
 "description": "Get notifications when you have new replies on your Disqus posts",
 "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "popup": "popup.html"
 },
 "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
 },
 "background_page": "background.html",
  "permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

*background.html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

*background.js:*

```
function poll() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange; // Implemented elsewhere.
    xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('http://disqus.com/api/3.0/messagesx/unread.json?user=<...>&api_key=<...>'), false);
    xhr.send(null);
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
}

function handleStateChange() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        var resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        updateUi(resp);
    }
}

function updateUi(json) {
    console.log("JSON: ", json);
}
```

*popup.html:*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Disqus notifier</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateButtonClicked() {
            chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().poll();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="updateButtonClicked()">Update</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The `xhr.send(null);` line is what logs the `101` error. In the event handler `handleStateChange`, `this.responseText` is an empty string, causing `JSON.parse` to fail with `Unexpected end of input`.

So: What am I missing in order to be allowed to make cross-domain AJAX calls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got an error in your background.js....

```
xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('http://disqus.com/api/3.0/messagesx/unread.json?user=<...>&api_key=<...>'), false);
```

...should be.....

```
xhr.open("GET", 'http://disqus.com/api/3.0/messagesx/unread.json?user=<...>&api_key=<...>', false);
```

chrome.extension.getURL is for getting the url of a file in your extension.
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL
You can make xhr requests from more than just the background page (pretty sure its any page in your extension now, including content scripts).
Chrome will not block xhr calls from an unpacked extension.

Comment: That was the sound of me smacking my forehead. The `getURL` call was a relic from some earlier experimentation. Thank you!